# How much memory do Java event filters take?

Tags: events, memory, filter, java-8, event-handling

In my program, I have several dozen Java `Panes` which have several event filters each.  However, at any given time, only one or two `Panes` are visible and the rest are not visible.  When the `Panes` are not visible, the event filters are not needed.  Is it worth it for me to remove the event filters from the `Panes` when the `Panes` are not visible?  Do event filters consume enough memory for me to be concerned about them being present even when their respective `Panes` are not visible to the user?

Thanks to all in advance!

Comment: Why do you think, an event filter on an unused `Pane` bears more to worry about than the unused `Pane` itself?

Comment: The filter is likely to be less than 0.1% of the size of the Pane. If in doubt I would so a memory profile, or a `jmap -histo` and see which objects are taking up the most space.